Spring Boot Profile not override property
I have a Spring Boot application 3.1.3 using two yml profiles
application.yml
application-prod.yml

The problem is that when I start the application using the prod profile, it is not overwriting this application.yml property with this property.
application properties
    ---
        spring:
          profiles:
            active: prod
          cloud.config:
            label: main
            uri: https://config-server-main

It continues to use this application.yml property
  cloud.config:
    label: qa
    uri: https://config-server-qa

What is the correct way to overwrite?

It seems you use the same format in both files, but they different. In properties we use a.b.c=xxx, in yaml instead points we use identations as in your example and colons instead points

In contrast to a Spring Boot application, a Spring Cloud application features a bootstrap context that is the parent of the application context. Although both of them share the same Environment, they have different conventions for locating the external configuration files.
The bootstrap context is searching for a bootstrap.properties or a bootstrap.yaml file, whereas the application context is searching for an application.properties or an application.yaml file.
See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bootstrapping

You want

Spring Boot Profile not override property

but Spring Boot will never override. There are two separated cases: No profile, and has profile.
See few tricks at here Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files for your need.
